# How do I make main wrapper stretch to content and get rid of overflow?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a box-text widget, and have some issues finding what is causing me trouble. When I scale it down I get overflow of text from the left box instead of it stretching to fit the box - so that the box gain the height of the content inside. I am not sure what I need to change in order to make it fit instead of overflow. Is it using position that messes it up? Or is it using % or flex? I hope someone can guide me!

```css
.section-main {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1650px;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #EDF3F7;
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  outline-offset: -25px;
}

.box-2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box-2 img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box-content {
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-boxes {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-main">
  <div class="box-1">
    <div class="box-content">
      <p>Texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-boxes">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M224 256A128 128 0 1 0 224 0a128 128 0 1 0 0 256zm-45.7 48C79.8 304 0 383.8 0 482.3C0 498.7 13.3 512 29.7 512H418.3c16.4 0 29.7-13.3 29.7-29.7C448 383.8 368.2 304 269.7 304H178.3z"/></svg>
          <div> text text text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-boxes">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M224 256A128 128 0 1 0 224 0a128 128 0 1 0 0 256zm-45.7 48C79.8 304 0 383.8 0 482.3C0 498.7 13.3 512 29.7 512H418.3c16.4 0 29.7-13.3 29.7-29.7C448 383.8 368.2 304 269.7 304H178.3z"/></svg>
          <div> text text text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-boxes">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M224 256A128 128 0 1 0 224 0a128 128 0 1 0 0 256zm-45.7 48C79.8 304 0 383.8 0 482.3C0 498.7 13.3 512 29.7 512H418.3c16.4 0 29.7-13.3 29.7-29.7C448 383.8 368.2 304 269.7 304H178.3z"/></svg>
          <div> text text text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1697789179905-948d4844510d?auto=format&fit=crop&q=80&w=1974&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you have a main flex container `section-main`  wrapping `.box-1` and `.box2`. But then you have `.box-content` containing those `<p>` elements, with `position: absolute`. Why? when the main container gets stretched, that box is lifted because you have `top: 50%` and a translate transform... so it's not overflowing it's actually hiding content slipping away from the viewport. Why don't you just get rid of it?

Comment: The idea with absolute in .box-content was to center everything within the div - but you're right, that's the one causing the issue. I cannot get it to center-center with margin: 0 auto; so I will have to think of some other way to keep it in the middle

Comment: - And thanks for the answer, makes sense it is pushed out of the viewport, I did not think of that. I was able to solve the issue, and learned a bit on the way!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make a few small changes here.

First, change `.box-content` to this:

```
.box-content{
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

`position: absolute` is taking elements out of the element's flow. You don't need it.

Next - **and this is only one of a zillion ways** - use `display: grid` and `place-items: center` to center `.box-1`.

Grid is available in every browser that matters.

```
.box-1 {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  background: #EDF3F7;
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  outline-offset: -25px;
}
```

There are other ways of improving what you have, but the above will resolve your issue.